# Laravel Horizon

Tags: php, laravel-10

I installed the Laravel Horizon but I run the `php artisan horizon` return to me this error:

```
Class "Redis" not found

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector.php:81
     77▕      * @throws \LogicException
     78▕      */
     79▕     protected function createClient(array $config)
     80▕     {
  ➜  81▕         return tap(new Redis, function ($client) use ($config) {
     82▕             if ($client instanceof RedisFacade) {
     83▕                 throw new LogicException(
     84▕                     extension_loaded('redis')
     85▕                         ? 'Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension.'

  i   A class import is missing: You have a missing class import. Try importing this class: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis`.

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector.php:34
      Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector::createClient()

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector.php:38
      Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector::Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\{closure}()
```

I'm expecting the message that was a successful.